# Trigger an action in the top level from within an iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an application loading in an `iframe`. What I am currently doing is the following:

1. the top document creates a `div` with a spinning wheel
2. the `iframe` starts loading
3. as soon as the iframe has loaded, the `onload` event is triggered to hide the `div` with the spinning wheel
4. but the `iframe` still has to load assets (CSS, JS, ...)

The problem that I have is that step number 4 is quite long, and I would like to keep on showing the spinning wheel (remove the `onload` event from the iframe definition). As soon as the `iframe` has been fully loaded, I would like to trigger an event in the top-level document.

How do I trigger an event in the top level from within an `iframe`? `jQuery` would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in your iframe code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         parent.hideSpinningWheel();
});
```

you will have to create a function called hideSpinningWheel that do what you want in your parent page.